# Display list items in console

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to display the items in my list via the console and I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Data is added to a list from a SQL server with the following code:

**List:**

```
namespace SSIS_FileWatcher

{
    public class WikiList //custom list
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Code to add data to list:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace SSIS_FileWatcher
{
    public class getWikiData
    {
        public List<WikiList> Source()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("DEV-BRMSQL01")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT source FROM [REFERENCE].[KRI_METRIC_WIKI_AND_INGESTION_SCHEDULE] ", connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    List<WikiList> entries = new List<WikiList>();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        WikiList w = new WikiList();
                        w.Source = (string)reader["Source"];
                        //w.Metric_ID = (string)reader["Metric_ID"];
                        //w.name = (string)reader["name"];
                        entries.Add(w);
                    }
                }
            }

            return List<WikiList>;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SSIS_FileWatcher
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        public string path = @"\\p1l-nas-02\EntTechBURM_DATA\PRD\";

        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                try 
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                    //add code to display list in console

                    await Task.Delay(60*1000, stoppingToken);
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the last code sample, I commented where I would like to show the results from my list. If anyone can show me how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, set the return type of getWikiData to `List<WikiList>()`.
(this you have done after an edit)

Then after calling `getWikiData.Source()`, you can create a string list like so:

```
var wikis = new getWikiData().Source();
string str = String.Join("\r\n", wikis.Select(x => x.Source));
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

If you want to add a bullet like structure, this can be achieved this way:

```
var wikis = new getWikiData().Source();
if (wikis.Count > 0) 
{
  string str = "\t- " + String.Join("\r\n\t- ", wikis.Select(x => x.Source));
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

**edit after your comment**

I modified your method to work, beware that you renamed the method:

```
    public List<WikiList> Source()
    {
        List<WikiList> entries = new List<WikiList>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("DEV-BRMSQL01")))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT source FROM [REFERENCE].[KRI_METRIC_WIKI_AND_INGESTION_SCHEDULE] ", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    WikiList w = new WikiList();
                    w.Source = (string)reader["Source"];
                    //w.Metric_ID = (string)reader["Metric_ID"];
                    //w.name = (string)reader["name"];
                    entries.Add(w);
                }
            }
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my getWikiData code to return `List<WikiList>()` but I don't believe I am doing it correctly. Any pointers?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I also made the edit in your question

Comment: The return is working as expected! However, I now can't call my method with your code:
`var wikis = getWikiData();
string str = String.Join("\r\n", wikis.Select(x => x.Source));
Console.WriteLine(str);`

I'm aware that I changed the name of the method, but even changing `getWikiData()` to `Source()` doesn't work.

Comment: the way you set it up (which is questionable), you need to do something like : 
 new getWikiData().Source()

Comment: I made some edits to my answer, try those.

Comment: Thank you. That works, now I'm just getting a 'System.InvalidCastException'. I guess it can't covert a data type somewhere. 

You mentioned that I probably set it up wrong, which is not surprising, I'm still very much a novice. Even though it's outside the scope of my initial question, would you be open to explaining how you might set something like this up?

Comment: C# is very well documented, please see the microsoft site for the fundamentals, they are easy to understand and will give you a jumpstart in better programming: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions 
For a start, I find good naming is really important, getWikiData for a class is not a good name. Call it WikiDataProvider, WikiDataService, or WikiDataRepository. Rename Source() to GetWikiLists(). The implementation looks good, I'm no expert. I would constructor-inject the WikiDataProvider into the worker, store it and then use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240964/discussion-between-michael-s-palatsi-and-cedric-moers).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JavaScriptSerializer class (add reference to System.Web.Extensions):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

after that

```
var wikis = getWikiData();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(wikis);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Also, you can use Newtonsoft
ref- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternative method (Cedric's will work, but if there's lots of data it may look like nothing's happening in the console for a while; so you may desire to print each line as it's retrieved):

If so, you could tweak the class definition to:

```
public class WikiList //custom list
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    
    public void WriteToConsole() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Source);
    }
}
```

Allowing `getWikiData` to change to:

```
public class getWikiData
{
    public List<WikiData> Entries {get;set;}

    public getWikiData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("DEV-BRMSQL01")))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT source FROM [REFERENCE].[KRI_METRIC_WIKI_AND_INGESTION_SCHEDULE] ", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Entries = new List<WikiList>();

                WikiList w = new WikiList();
                w.Source = (string)reader["Source"];
                //w.Metric_ID = (string)reader["Metric_ID"];
                //w.name = (string)reader["name"];
                Entries.Add(w);
                w.WriteToConsole();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meaning you just call `getWikiData` in your worker method:

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            try 
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

                getWikiData wikiData = new getWikiData(); 

                await Task.Delay(60*1000, stoppingToken);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Andrew, this is actually producing results in the console! However, it looks like I'm stuck in a loop as it keeps repeating the data and I'm not sure where that would be happening. Any advice?

Comment: See my edit - just realised there were two levels of the `while (reader.read())` loop

Answer (score 1):

you don' t need WikiData class

```
 public List<string> Source()
    {
        List<string> entries = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("DEV-BRMSQL01")))
        {
             ...
           while (reader.Read()) entries.Add(reader["Source"].ToString());
            reader.Close();
         }
        return entries;
    }
```

and how to display

```
 var getWikiData= new getWikiData();
 var source =getWikiData.Source(); 
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Join("\n\r",source));
```